# Can we add an extra button on woocommerce shop page and use it to send the product info including image in a mail?

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic

1. I want to add an extra button after "add to cart"
2. It will open a form with only email field
3. After submitting an email id, it will send product name, image, 
   description to that email id

Thanx in advance.

[image]

Comment: Some additional information like a short "hello, somewhat about it your problem and thanks" may help. Have a look at this post from me. All you need to do is to add the WP_Mail function at some point. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/355057/add-a-custom-button-with-custom-link-after-add-to-cart-for-every-product/355066#355066

Comment: Actually, I was going to thank everyone after their comment on this question.

Comment: But thanx for taking out time for my problem