# Add a custom button with custom link after add to cart for every product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Let's say I need to add a custom button so visitors can visit the product's external site. That way they can visit the product's site.

What I want to achieve is as follows:

1. Add a custom button after the add to cart button;
2. The link to the custom button needs to be set in each product edition.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Gabriel can you please provide me that finalised code so that I can use it to show a custom button on my product page??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to WPSE.

You can use a WordPress WooCommerce hook to achive this. Just like WordPress itself, WooCommerce also allows you to use hooks and filters to customize your shop. You need to add the following code to the functions.php of your current theme.

This code adds a simple link after the WooCommerce add to cart button.

```
// This function gets the value for the the custom fields from the database and adds it to the frontend output function
function wpse_add_custom_link_output() {
    $external_link = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_custom_product_text_field', true);
    $html = '<a href="'.$external_link.'" class="custom-button-class" target="_blank" title="'.__('External product link','woocommerce').'">'.$external_link.'</a>';
    echo $html;
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'wpse_add_custom_link_output', 10, 0 ); 
// This function creates the field in the backend
function wpse_add_custom_link_field(){
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    echo '<div class="product_custom_field">';
    // Custom Product Text Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_custom_product_text_field',
            'placeholder' => __('Paste product link here', 'woocommerce'),
            'label' => __('Custom product link', 'woocommerce'),
            'desc_tip' => 'true'
        )
    );
    echo '</div>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'wpse_add_custom_link_field');
// this function saves the link/text field
function wpse_save_custom_link_field($post_id){
    // Custom Product Text Field
    $woocommerce_custom_product_text_field = $_POST['_custom_product_text_field'];
    if (!empty($woocommerce_custom_product_text_field))
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_product_text_field', 
    esc_attr($woocommerce_custom_product_text_field));
}
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'wpse_save_custom_link_field');
```

You may want to add some css like:

```
a.custom-button-class:link,
a.custom-button-class:visited {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
a.custom-button-class:hover,
a.custom-button-class:focus {
    /* some hover style */
}
```

Please accept the answer as correct if it worked for you. I have tested this code with theme 2020.

Comment: Hey @user3135691, the code add the link to my product edit screen. But the button does not show after the Download button, since I'm using Downloadable Products. Not sure if this change something your code. As there is no add to cart button, but the download one.

Comment: You were just talking about "the product" - I did assume you were using WooCommerce. In that case, you need to browse the documentation of the plugin which you are using.

Comment: Thanks, @user3135691. I'am talking about WooCommerce. But I'm using "Single Product" for Download Products option (the checkbox on every product edit screen). Members have access to the product via a Download Button so they download it. I just need to add another button after the download button in the product page. See this: [link](https://prntscr.com/qeg8lz). What you have build above is working in the product edit screen (I can inset the link), but the button is not showing after the Download button or any other place.

Comment: Hey @user3135691, I managed to make your code work by changing the hook. I have send my edit to review after that I will mark your answer as correct. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you, I hope it works for you :)