# Add multiple custom buttons with custom links after add to cart button for every product

Tags: buttons

Rather than using product variations, I would like to have buttons for each variation (usually two or three) under the Add to Cart button. These buttons would link to a new page with the specific product listed, so they'd need to be custom for each product. I would like to be able to enter the link and the button text in the Product Data / General section. The answer user3135691 gave to a similar question (pasted below) is very close, and allows for the Custom Product Link on each product, but I haven't been able to get it into the form of a button with different text than the link, and it doesn't have a field for the button text.

A single field in which I could write custom HTML that included the URL, CSS and class would work perfectly too.

Also, as mentioned, I'd need to be able to create a few buttons and was wondering if I'd just create multiple snippets.

[Add a custom button with custom link after add to cart for every product](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/355057/add-a-custom-button-with-custom-link-after-add-to-cart-for-every-product)

```
// This function gets the value for the the custom fields from the database and adds it to the frontend output function
function wpse_add_custom_link_output() {
    $external_link = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_custom_product_text_field', true);
    $html = '<a href="'.$external_link.'" class="custom-button-class" target="_blank" title="'.__('External product link','woocommerce').'">'.$external_link.'</a>';
    echo $html;
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'wpse_add_custom_link_output', 10, 0 ); 
// This function creates the field in the backend
function wpse_add_custom_link_field(){
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    echo '<div class="product_custom_field">';
    // Custom Product Text Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_custom_product_text_field',
            'placeholder' => __('Paste product link here', 'woocommerce'),
            'label' => __('Custom product link', 'woocommerce'),
            'desc_tip' => 'true'
        )
    );
    echo '</div>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'wpse_add_custom_link_field');
// this function saves the link/text field
function wpse_save_custom_link_field($post_id){
    // Custom Product Text Field
    $woocommerce_custom_product_text_field = $_POST['_custom_product_text_field'];
    if (!empty($woocommerce_custom_product_text_field))
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_product_text_field', 
    esc_attr($woocommerce_custom_product_text_field));
}
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'wpse_save_custom_link_field');
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing the code @Buttered_Toast. I'm new to Wordpress and WooCommerce and appreciate your help!

Comment: I've found a simple way to add content below the Add to Cart button using this:

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_after_addtocart_button_func' );

function add_content_after_addtocart_button_func() {

// Echo content.

echo '<div class="second_content">Place your content here!</div>';

}

Replacing the "Place your content here" text with HTML creates a button with an external link but, like using HTML widgets, it's the same for all product pages. So, I'm wondering if there's a way to change the Custom Product Text Field above to an HTML field?